# Masking Affiliate URL using $post_slug after "/go/"

Tags: custom-field, redirect

I am trying to figure out how can I redirect a masked URL based on a custom field URL. If I have a masked URL:

```
echo '<a href="https://domain.com/go/'. $post_slug .'/" class="button">Click here to save ' . $discount_percentage . '% on ' . $title . '</a>';
```

Then how can I redirect this URL `https://example.com/go/wordpress` to a custom field url that holds a value like `https://wordpress.org`

The redirect must be configured in such a way that it will only redirect URL with `/go/` and followed by `post_slug`. I do not want to redirect normal posts that are using `domain.com/post_slug =` Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) combined with a custom query variable and hooking into `template_redirect` to catch your `/go/...` urls.

First up: the rewrite rule. This just maps a regex pattern to an set of query params on `index.php`. I'm going to use a post ID here rather than a slug. Makes things a bit easier in our catch/redirect function.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse205416_add_rule');
function wpse205416_add_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^go/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?wpse205416_go=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

the `wpse205416_go` bit is significant, we'll fetch it later. WordPress discards query variables it does't know about so we have to register it by hooking into `query_vars`.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse205416_add_var');
function wpse205416_add_var(array $vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'wpse205416_go';
    return $vars;
}
```

And now we can hook into `template_redirect` and look for our `wpse205416_go` variable. If present, fetch the post (to make sure it exists) and fetch the URL and redirect. The onlything interesting here is the `_wpse205416_not_found` function which just makes sure we actually 404. Calling `$wp_query->set_404()` doesn't send the correct HTTP status.

```
function _wpse205416_not_found()
{
    global $wp_query;
    status_header(404);
    $wp_query->set_404();
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse205416_catch_go');
function wpse205416_catch_go()
{
    $id = get_query_var('wpse205416_go');
    if (!$id) {
        return; // not a redirect
    }

    $post = get_post($id);
    if (!$post) {
        return _wpse205416_not_found(); // not a valid post ID, 404 it!
    }

    // whatever your meta key is
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpse205416_go_url', true);
    if (!$url) {
        return _wpse205416_not_found(); // no url, 404 it!
    }

    // always exit after redirecting
    wp_safe_redirect($url, 302);
    exit;
}
```

If you're interested in learning more about the rewrite api, I wrote a fairly extensive [tutorial](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/) about it.

Comment: Hi Chris, It's awesome and i feel something closer to what i want to achieve. Actually, the links are not redirecting and it may be because of the use of post slugs. Can you please check the [link](https://wpcouponcodes.com) and you will find that on the main page, below each post there is a button saying "Click here to save % on Post_Title" Actually, this is achieved via custom field "url" and the link is generated using post_slug. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I pasted the above code in the functions.php but still wondering what to do. Please guide in detail. Thanks

Comment: `function display_custom_fields() {
 $title = apply_filters( 'genesis_post_title_text', get_the_title() );
 global $post;
 $post_slug = $post->post_name;
 $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url', true ) );
 
 if ( ! ( $url || $starts_on || $ends_on || $coupon_code || $discount_percentage ) ) {
  return;
 }
 if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
  echo '<a href="https://wpcouponcodes.com/go/'. $post_slug .'/" class="button">Click here to save ' . $discount_percentage . '% on ' . $title . '</a>';
 }
}`